# Why is hashing so slow?

Tags: go, hash

I am working on a web application. In order to hash passwords I used following logic

```
package core

import (
    "math/rand"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

type User struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

type Hasher interface {
    HashPassword()
}

func (u *User) HashPassword() {
    cost := rand.Intn(28) + 4

    //TODO: Handle error
    hashedPassword, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(u.Password), cost)
    u.Password = string(hashedPassword)
}
```

Then while handling requests

```
func HandleRegister(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var user core.User
    var hasher core.Hasher
    hasher = &user

    //TODO: Handle error
    _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&user)

    hasher.HashPassword()

    fmt.Println(user)
}
```

I am using randomized costs for hashing for security reasons. Problem is that when cost became big, process is really slow. I am using `Postman` to send request to my server but it is really slow. Why is that so? Is my implementation wrong?

Note: In my SQLite database, I choose `TEXT` type for password column to store hashed password. Would it be better to use `BLOB` type instead of `TEXT`?

Comment: To add to what kichik said (all true): password hashing functions are intentionally slow to make the cost of brute force attacks computationally prohibitive. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) for more details.

Comment: Don't use a random cost; use a cost that makes it slow enough to be secure. Which comes to the next point... *being slow is what makes them secure*. You don't *want* it to be fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your maximum cost is 32. That means 2^32 rounds of key expansion. Even a simple loop that just goes over every number between 1 and 2^32 without doing anything would take a few seconds. You need to cap your cost to a more reasonable number.

Furthermore, your minimum cost of 4 is way too small. That's just 16 rounds. It would make cracking the password way easier than it should be.

Why are you even using a random number? [Read this](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/17207/113807) for a better way of selecting the cost.

> The number of iterations that gives at least 250 ms to compute